# Programmatically selecting an <option> works in Opera, but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a userscript that has to change a whole list of options depending on 1 option in a select. In Opera this script works fine, but not in Chrome (Yes, jQuery is available).

HTML:

```
<select id="autoConfig-gametype" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="1" selected="">1. [RECOMMENDED] All latest Game-settings, Paladin, archers, simple tech smithy</option>
    <option value="2">2. No paladin, archers, simple tech system [TWMASTERS Settings]</option>
    <option value="3">3. No paladin, no archers. Packages, 3 lvl tech-system. [CLASSIC]</option>
</select>

<select name="game::tech">
    <option value="0">0: 10 level</option>
    <option value="1">1: 3 level (up to 15)</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2: Simple</option>
</select>
```

With jQuery I have used `attr` and `prop`, but both have no result in Chrome. The select that needs to be manipulated does not change.

jQuery:

```
$("#autoConfig-gametype").change(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();

    switch(value)
    {
        case "1":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeProp("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeAttr("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(0)").attr("selected",true); 
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(0)").prop("selected",true); 
            break;
        case "2":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeProp("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeAttr("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(1)").attr("selected",true); 
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(1)").prop("selected",true);  
            break;
        case "3":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeProp("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option").removeAttr("selected");
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(2)").attr("selected",true); 
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(2)").prop("selected",true);  
            break;
    }
});
```

I am kind of stuck here right now, because I am making this script for someone who only uses Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removeProp and removeAttr were not working, using `.prop('property', true/false)` works. Please see the fiddle in Chrome.

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6bxew/

```
$("#autoConfig-gametype").change(function()
{
  var value = $(this).val();

  switch(value)
  {
    case "1":
        // Game > Tech
        $("[name='game\:\:tech'] option").prop("selected", false); 
        $("[name='game\:\:tech'] option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
        break;
    case "2":
        // Game > Tech
        $("[name='game\:\:tech'] option").prop("selected", false);
        $("[name='game\:\:tech'] option:eq(1)").prop("selected",true);  
        break;
    case "3":
        // Game > Tech
        $("[name='game::tech'] option").prop("selected", false);
        $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(2)").prop("selected",true);  
        break;
  }
});
```

​

Comment: This works, but only visually. It does change it visually, but in the DOM (according to Chrome), the default option still says that it's selected. I'm not sure how a form with an action will use this?

Comment: Chrome DOM isn't changing in the console, for whatever reason, but [alerting out the selected value is showing the right value](http://jsfiddle.net/6bxew/1/).

Comment: Ok, then this script should work properly now :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
$("#autoConfig-gametype").change(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();

    switch(value)
    {
        case "1":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(0)").prop("selected",true); 
            break;
        case "2":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(1)").prop("selected",true);  
            break;
        case "3":
            // Game > Tech
            $("[name='game::tech'] option:eq(2)").prop("selected",true);  
            break;
    }
});​
```

[jsFiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aatck/)

From `removeProp` documentation

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: This works, but only visually. It does change it visually, but in the DOM (according to Chrome), the default option still says that it's selected. I'm not sure how a form with an action will use this?

Comment: @Rune: Not sure what you're doing but this statement `$("[name='game::tech'] option:selected")` gives me the correct option after the `switch`